# CodeIgniter: ion auth library giving salt error while creating new user

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, ion-auth

When I tried to create user with `store_salt` to `FALSE` it is giving below error

```
$config['salt_length'] = 10;
$config['store_salt']  = FALSE;
```

**Here is the error**

```
Error Number: 1364

Field 'salt' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `company`, `phone`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `ip_address`, `created_on`, `last_login`, `active`) VALUES ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', '466', 'xxx.yyy', '', 'xxx@yyy.com', '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0', 1385641604, 1385641604, 1)

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\atlas-dev\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

When I tried with `store_sal` to `TRUE` it is not giving error but than it is not considering the password correct and user cannot login.

Can you help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error Number: 1364** occurs most probably due to default not set or null value not allowed.

**Change the salt field from "NOT NULL" to "ALLOW NULL".**

> ALTER TABLE users MODIFY salt varchar(40) null;

This should reset it's default to "ALLOW NULL", allowing you to insert a record without a value for salt field

If salt is used ,

```
$config['store_salt']  = TRUE;
```

It will change your password encryption algorithm,
 default password, 'password', changes to
 fbaa5e216d163a02ae630ab1a43372635dd374c0 with default salt.

Answer (score 0):

This 'store_salt' setting obviously tells Ion Auth whether to insert something in the `salt` field or not. The problem is that this field doesn't have a default value and you're not inserting anything into it.
So, either alter the field definition to have a default value or use a salt.

Comment: One thing I understood that it is not sending any value. But than where I can set the salt default value? in ion_auth config file or where?

Comment: No idea, not an IonAuth user. The problem that you asked about is one with how your table is structured.